# Submenu items in Nautilus right-click menu

Tags: python, gtk, gnome, nautilus

I am trying to write an extension for nautilus, which add an item to the menu that appears when you right-click a file (as shown in image)

[image]

However, I would like to add a submenu to my custom menu item.

I downloaded a 'nautilus-python' package which includes examples of how to write extensions for Nautilus (and so far it turned out to be the best/only documentation i found). In it, is a file called submenu.py, which contains the following:

```
import nautilus

class ExampleMenuProvider(nautilus.MenuProvider):

    def get_file_items(self, window, files):
        menuitem = nautilus.MenuItem('ExampleMenuProvider::Foo', 'Foo', '')

        submenu = nautilus.Menu()
        menuitem.set_submenu(submenu)

        menuitem = nautilus.MenuItem('ExampleMenuProvider::Bar','Bar','')
        submenu.append_item(menuitem)

        return menuitem,

    # FIXME: Why isn't this working?
    def get_background_items(self, window, file):
        submenu = nautilus.Menu()
        submenu.append_item(nautilus.MenuItem('ExampleMenuProvider::Bar', 'Bar', ''))

        menuitem = nautilus.MenuItem('ExampleMenuProvider::Foo', 'Foo', '')
        menuitem.set_submenu(submenu)

        return menuitem,
```

ps: i didn't add "# FIX ME: Why isnt this working?". that is actually included in the example

The code doesn't work. Even if i take out the second function and leave just the first one, it doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution.

1. you need a **init** function declared.
2. had to make some variable name change to the example above

   ```
   import nautilus

   class ExampleMenuProvider(nautilus.MenuProvider):
       def __init__(self):
           pass

       def get_file_items(self, window, files):
           submenu = nautilus.Menu()

           item = nautilus.MenuItem('Nautilus::sbi','Nau-T','image')
           item.set_submenu(submenu)

           item_two = nautilus.MenuItem('Nautilus::s','www','image')
           submenu.append_item(item_two)

           return item,
   ```

Comment: If I want to add another submenu into 'Nautilus::sbi' from a different script, How can I do that? I have to get the menu_item first? Isn't it? Otherwise it creates duplicates menu.